# Filter datagridview using combobox and textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to filter my datagridview by searching a keyword in a textbox from its combobox item where the source is the column name from my table. I don't have any idea how to do it in c#.

All I know is this vb.net code:

```
Private Sub txtkeyword_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtkeyword.TextChanged
        
Dim qry As String
        
If cmbfilter.Text = "EMPLOYEE_ID" Then
            qry = "select * from tblpayslip where EMPLOYEE_ID like '%" & txtkeyword.Text & "%'"
       
 Else
            qry = "select * from tblemployee"
        
End If

    connect()
    conn.Open()
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand

    cmd.CommandText = qry

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        Dim dtpayslip As New DataTable
        dtpayslip.Load(dr)
        dgvpayslip.DataSource = dtpayslip
    End If

    dgvpayslip.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "EMPLOYEE_ID"
    dgvpayslip.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "SALARY_PER_DAY"
    dgvpayslip.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "NO_OF_DAYS_WORKED"
    dgvpayslip.Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "GROSS_PAY"
    dgvpayslip.Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "SSS"
    dgvpayslip.Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "PAG_IBIG"
    dgvpayslip.Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "TAX"
    dgvpayslip.Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "NET_PAY"

    dgvpayslip.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't always need to go for SQL which will lack in performance, possibly you can fill datatable on form_load event and set rowfilter on textchange() event.

Follow the below piece of code on textchange event and move your SQL functionalities to form_load event

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
{
    var dt = (DataTable)dgvpayslip.DataSource;
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("{0} like '%{1}%'",comboBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"), txtkeyword.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
    dgvpayslip.Refresh();
}
```